# Send the consumed message from Consumer to Producer with Masstransit

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I sent a message from the Producer to the Consumer projects.
Then I want to send a different message from Consumer to the Producer when I got the first message.
I'm doing this with the below code.

```
public class CommandMessageConsumer : IConsumer<CommandMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CommandMessage> context)
    {
        // I'm getting the message Consumer -> Consumer
        var message = context.Message;
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message from Producer : {message.MessageString}");

        // I'm sending the message Consumer -> Consumer
        _ = context.Publish(new CommandMessage(message.Id, message.MessageString));
    }
}
```

I'm getting the message Consumer->Producer but the issue is it continues to send and doesn't stop on the console. Which means to infinity!

Also the Producer service part:

```
public class PCommandMessageConsumer : IConsumer<CommandMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CommandMessage> context)
    {
        var message = context.Message;
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"------------------Message from Consumer to Producer : {message.MessageString}");
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest [watching some videos](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri2MBx6BjPum5j9_MMdIfM9C) to understand how MassTransit works. And if you want to use request/response, that's [documented](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by setting the ReceiveEndpoint queue names differently.
Making them the same (in my case "samplequeue")fixed the infinite loop.
I guess making them different queue names blocked the acknowledgment and this caused a send-loop until getting the received acknowledgment.

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
                    mt.UsingRabbitMq((cntxt, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host("localhost", "/", c =>
                        {
                            c.Username("guest");
                            c.Password("guest");
                        });
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("samplequeue", (c) =>
                        {
                            c.Consumer<PCommandMessageConsumer>();
                        });
                    }));
```